# Sum all int values from a list of object flutter

Tags: dart

I have a list of an object. I want to iterate through the object list and sum a particular list of int. How do I achieve this?

```
 List<Tasks> tasks;

 void getSpentTotal(){
    List<int> amountSpent = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      amountSpent.add(tasks[i].availableBudget);
      spentSoFar += amountSpent[i];
    }
  }
```

**Model Class**

```
class Tasks {
  int availableBudget;
  String totalBudget;

  Tasks(
      {this.totalBudget,
        this.availableBudget});

  Tasks.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   totalBudget = json['totalBudget'];       
    availableBudget = json['availableBudget'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['totalBudget'] = this.totalBudget;
    data['availableBudget'] = this.availableBudget;
    return data;
  }
  static List<Tasks> fromJsonList(List<dynamic> _list) {
    return _list.map((_tasks) => Tasks.fromJson(_tasks)).toList();
  }
}
```

So basically, what I want is to sum up my `availableBudget` and show the value.

Comment: Which list do you precisely want to do operations to?

Comment: So what is the problem in your code and please tell what list is it?

Comment: please review my question @CodeDexter

Comment: please review my question @TheBossProSniper

Comment: Your `getSpentTotal` does not make much sense since you are using the `i` variable outside of the for-loop and therefore the variable does not exists. Do you just want to sum all `availableBudget` in `_bloc.tasks`?

Comment: Also, why is `getSpentTotal` marked as `async` but does not return any `Future` or have any `await` inside?

Comment: The question is confusing in so many ways. Like.. (1) `_tasks.length` is used for number of for loops and inside it some `_bloc.tasks` is used for data. (2) Names of the variables. If you are trying to get total amount spent so far, how does adding up `availableBudget` give you total spent? (3) An unused `List<Tasks> tasks` is declared at the top just to add to the confusion. There are even more things I could point out. Maybe if you just make your code to make more sense first, maybe there will be no problem left for you. Summing integer values from a list of objects is not a problem usually.

Comment: @julemand101yes. I want to sum all availableBudget ib _bloc.tasks which is a List<Tasks>

Answer (score 1):

You could use fold to sum up the field.

```
void getSpentTotal() async{
    final amountSpent = _bloc.tasks.fold(0, (acc, cur) => acc + cur.availableBudget);
    setState(() {
      spentSoFar += amountSpent;
    });
}
```

Comment: Changed it into using `fold` instead since that was properly what you have in mind. Reduce would only work if the elements in the list reducing was also int. So we could e.g. reduce the `amountSpent` list. But we could also, (as your answer is) just sum the values and have the sum directly.

Comment: I think you mixed up my question. Can review my post please?